# Process large csv file using mysql load data infile

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo, laravel-5.3

I am trying to read CSV file with 500k rows and 81 columns and insert it in database. CSV size is 160 MB. I have to process it every 3-4 hours. Every 3-4 hours I will have a new CSV with some new records and some existing. For that I have followed many methods but nothing working perfectly.

**Method 1**: It reads all records but takes too much time. It took more than 1 hour to read 200k records and then time out.

```
$file    = fopen($path, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
}
```

As a solution: I can increase php limit, excution time and memory limit to avoid this error but I feel it is very slow.

**Method 2:**

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE products.csv INTO TABLE tmp_tbl LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES";

DB::select($query);
```

It gave following error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1 (SQL: LOAD DATA LOCAL
>   INFILE 'products.csv' INTO TABLE tmp_tbl LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES)

**Method 3:**

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'products.csv' INTO TABLE tmp_tbl LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES";

DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
```

or

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_path."' INTO TABLE tmp_tbl LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES";

DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
```

Got following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1

**Method 4**

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_path."' INTO TABLE tmp_tbl";

DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
```

Got following error

> PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away

**Method 5**

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_path."' INTO TABLE tmp_tbl";
DB::select($query);
```

Got following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: LOAD DATA
>   LOCAL INFILE 'products.csv' INTO TABLE tmp_tbl)

Which method I should continue using and why I am getting all these errors? I want to process all records in less time without any error.

Comment: Why should method #1 take so much memory? Are you trying to build an array of all records from the csv before looping over that array to insert them into the database?

Comment: No I am not using array, I am accessing one by one row using fgetcsv and inserting/updating in database.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be high memory usage in any way; speed is potentially a problem, but thee should be no reason to increase memory

Comment: ok. any suggestions so that I can speed up process in method1?

Comment: Split an initial file in several small files and use several threads to process them in parallel.

Comment: It is dynamic process so how I can break file in parts? Any suggestion or link or example where I can see/read it?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this: `DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();` to the top of your script - your memory consumption may be coming from storing queries in memory.

Comment: @Jass - yes for method 1.